# open a terminal and executing a command in the opened terminal using c language

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I want to open a new terminal and run ssh session in that opened terminal. The code that I am using is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    char cmd[50];
    strcpy(cmd,"gnome-terminal");
    system(cmd);
    strcpy(cmd,"ssh 172.27.23.143");
    system(cmd);
}
```

But it is not working. Please help

Comment: `popen()` seems much suitable for your purpose. Refer: `man popen`

Comment: What is the error your are getting?

Comment: there is no error but after closing only the terminal opened due to first command the second command is executing but i want a bunch of commands to be executed int the same terminal

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do you should use the command in the following format:

```
void main()
{
    char cmd[50];
    strcpy(cmd,"gnome-terminal -e \"ssh 172.27.23.143\"");
    system(cmd);
    return;
}
```

To make the new terminal stay opened when the command completes:
In `gnome-terminal`

- Go to *Edit* -> *Profile Preferences* -> *Title*
- Click the Command tab.
- Select `Hold the terminal` from the drop-down menu labeled `When command exits`.
- You should create a new profile for that and execute with
  `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=MYPROFILE -e mycommand`

EDIT:
To chain multiple commands use:

`strcpy(cmd,"gnome-terminal -e \"ssh 172.27.23.143 && command1 && command2 && commandN\"");`

In shell we chain commands using the `&&` operator.

Comment: what if i want to perform another command on the same terminal

Comment: Why do you both use `strcpy` for a constant string?

Comment: @C.R.  Ofcourse, the code can simply be written as `char cmd[50] = "gnome-terminal -e \"ssh 172.27.23.143\"";` , but I prefer to maintain similarity with OP's code, as much as possible with focus on answering the real question.